# I want to implement a gallery view and when i clicked on particular

Tags: android, gallery

I want to implement a gallery view and when i clicked on particular image it will reflects on image switcher but here thing is that image is slidable means i can slide image from left to right

Comment: Try CoverFlow: https://github.com/Polidea/android-coverflow

Answer (score 0):

Make this on button click this will take you to gallery where you will be able to pick image.

```
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);                           
            startActivityForResult(i, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
```

And then you call onActivityResult like this .

```
     if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) 
        {

            Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };         
          Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
           String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));                        
           // image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));      

            image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
           cursor.close();
       }
```

This way picked image will apper  in your ImageView. I think that will be best choice for your app